# How to show snackbar throughout the Application?

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I have more than 3 Activity but let's just take three of them, BaseActivity, Splashscreen, MainActivity. Splashscreen and Mainactivity extends BaseActivity. 
Now i am showing a Snackbar inside the BaseActivity whenever I get failureresponse from the server. The response code is in BaseActivity and parallely i am transitioning from splashscreen to MainActivity.

The snackbar is not showing up? What could be the error? is there a way to make static snackbar? i have tried it but didnt get the getWindow from a static method?
 Anyone faced this problem?

Comment: put getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content) this as view in snackbar and make a function that shows the snack in base activity.

Comment: Not working......

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a **static method** in your utils and create snack bar in utils class and use anywhere in your app

```
     public static void showSnackBar(View view, String msg) {
        if (view != null) {
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
            TextView textView = snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
            textView.setMaxLines(5);
//snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 8, 20, 37));
            snackbar.show();
        }
    }
```

Use:

```
Utils.showSnackBar(getView(), failureMessage);
```

Comment: What's getView() ? Will it be available if I go from one activity to another activity? is it not activity-dependent because if it is then it will recreate whenever the activity recreates or new activity opens.

Comment: there is no method such getview()

Comment: No, i am using this method in the fragment, And fragment provide getView() return root view

Comment: you pass any view for your use

Comment: i passed the rootview() and call the above code in oncreate of baseactivity. My other two activities extend baseactivity so when i go from splashscreen to mainactivity it will create new BaseAcitivty and as soon as i go to the next activity the snackbar dismissed. I want to show snackbar which is Application based.

Comment: a snack bar is destroyed when activity is destroyed

Comment: So there is no way to show snackbar when going from one activity to another?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186596/discussion-between-milan-pansuriya-and-sniper).